# How do you reset MS OneDrive so files will sync?

Tags: hard-drive, sync, onedrive

I have OneDrive on my desktop computer and on my tablet and phone.

Everything was working great as far as files being sync and the retrieval was excellent no matter what device I was on.

I uploaded `Amazon cloud` (*their version of cloud*) and now when I turn my Computer ON says files could not be synced to Microsoft OneDrive.

Any ideas, Thanks

Comment: Tried this `%localappdata%\Microsoft\OneDrive\onedrive.exe /reset` ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

please refer to this official link for more information

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fix-OneDrive-sync-problems-with-Windows-10-Windows-7-or-Windows-Vista-83ab0d8a-8400-45b0-8dcf-dc8aa8a6bcf8